# Intercepting android mobile traffic using Burpsuite?

Tags: android, mobile

I have a problem with the burpsuite,when am trying to intercepting the android device traffic it didnt showing any error at all.i have installed CA certificate and my java version is compatable with it.

And i dont have any problems with the browser traffic it is working well.

Please help me out to get this issue.

Thanks in advance.